# close a modal popup from an iframe

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using modal.js to pop up dialog box in a page. When the user clicks on a link an iframe will show on a modal dialog box. There is a button inside that iframe. When the button clicks, the modal should be closed and page should redirect to another url. Is it posssible?

Comment: The answer is yes. What is modal.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [binding](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a custom event.

On the click, before you show the `iframe`, do the following in javascript:

```
// Bind a trigger
$('body').unbind('myUniqueEventName', SomeJavascriptFunction);
$('body').bind('myUniqueEventName', SomeJavascriptFunction);
```

Elsewhere in javascript define the function `SomeJavascriptFunction`:

```
function SomeJavascriptFunction(event, extraData) {
    // This is run when the button on the popup is clicked
    // You can pass along data using the extraData parameter
    // You can also redirect to another page
    var someData = extraData.someData; // Will contain 'someValue'
}
```

Now all we have to do is trigger the custom event from the iframe. We do this by adding the following code in the iframe when the button is clicked.

```
parent.$('body').trigger(
    'myUniqueEventName', {
        someData: 'someValue'
    });
});
```